# MySQL Left JOIN over 3 Tables with Policy for not allowed userid

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 Tables which should combined with an Left Join, thats so far ok. But now i only want some Informations e.g. only Gender is Male, thats ok too. Also show all rows where Gender IS Null, thats ok too. But now i only want to show allowed rows. Who are allowed is clarified before e.g. Dont show rows which have ID 1.  And thats the problem. E.g.

```
table1 
id | tab2_id | gender_id | bla

table2 
id | name | bla | blub

table3 
id | tabl_id | gender_id | allowed 
1  | 1       | 1         | 1 
2  | 2       | 1         | 2
```

Query so far:

```
Select table1. gender_id, table1.bla, table2.name, table2.bla 
From table1
Left Join table2 ON table1.tab2_id = table2.id
LEFT Join table3 on table1.tab2_id = table3.tab1_id
Where table1.gender_id = '1'
OR table1.gender_id IS NULL
AND table3.allowed <> 1
```

I hope this gets clear while its an example. The main Problem is the allowed one. I can Select all rows for Gender 1 but i dont want select these which are not allowed from some Users in Pollicy Table3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT table1.gender_id, table1.bla, table2.name, table2.bla 
  FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
    ON table1.tab2_id = table2.id LEFT JOIN table3 
    ON table1.tab2_id = table3.tab1_id 
   AND table3.allowed <> 1
 WHERE table1.gender_id = 1
    OR table1.gender_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Mm, not sure about the inverted commas, though.

Comment: Thx Peterm,

meanwhile i tried it again and found the solution. I have to write the OR as last Condition and than the Result is ok. Peterm i will test your advice. 
thx so far solved for me.

Comment: Hello peterm,i got now time to work further with this and have a new problem.i have in tabl3 not only allowed, but also a row for each entry with user_id,field_name and allowed.E.g 4,country,4 and in next line 4,gender,1 for the same user one entry for each field. if i now want to have all user which have gender  2 and country 53 this didnt work.i extended your code with and tabl3.allowed =4 and tabl3.gender=2 and tabl3.country=53. as left join. but i got also user who have the same country and gender but allowed is 1 and not two.do you have an solution for this.i tried some but all didnt work

Comment: Because of Characterlimitations: Sorry for the short answer. My next idea is to use 1 single row instead of many. so i would have one for each users with lots of rows. but my first idea is to be dynamicaly and expandable with lots of rows. perhaps you have a solution for my problem. thx

Comment: Hi, i think i got it. After houres of testing with subqueries and other and searching i found a possible solution with AND field_name IN(gender,country). I will test it further but it looks good ;)

Comment: Sorry for commenting but i will hold you uptodate. The last try didnt work and presently i dont know how to solve it except to redesign the tables or make 2 single sql queries. perhaps some one can help

Comment: @Sunghost In order to be able to further help you please consider to provide relevant sample data, preferably in a form of [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and post desired output based on this sample data (either commented in sqlfiddle or on some other site and provide a link to it).